# WeblogicのログオブジェクトをWebアプリケーションからフィルタリング出来ますか？

Tags: java, weblogic

```
<2014/12/19 17時15分53秒 JST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <ログ・ファイルC:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\datasource.logはローテーションされます。処理が停止した場合は、ログ・ファイルを再オープンしてください。これは、Windowsなど一部のプラットフォームで起こる可能性があります。> 
<2014/12/19 17時15分53秒 JST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <ログ・ファイルはC:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\datasource.log01725までローテーションされました。ログ・メッセージは引き続きC:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\datasource.logに記録されます。>
```

Weblogicを起動していると、上記のようなログメッセージが大量に出ることがあります。
これをWebアプリケーションからフィルタリング出来ないかと思い、

http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/wls/docs81/logging/filtering.html

上記URLを参考にフィルタクラスを作成し、Webアプリケーションに登録してみました。
そこで、いくつかのログオブジェクトはフィルタリング出来たのですが、
肝心の上記ログをフィルタリングすることが出来ませんでした。

Loggerオブジェクト、Handlerオブジェクトを取得するときのコンテキストを間違えているのかと思ったのですが、
どれを試してもフィルタにかかりませんでした。
上記のログをフィルタリングするにはこの方法ではいけないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

このログは、ログシステムそのものに関わるメッセージなので、別のクラスパス上でロードされた設定ファイルによって制御されているのではないか、と想像しました。LoggingServiceクラスが含まれるjarファイル等に、設定ファイルを埋め込んでみてはどうでしょうか。

追記：
リンク先の設定方法ドキュメントを後で読んだのですが、xmlやpropertiesファイルで設定するタイプの仕組みではないようですね。失礼しました...。